# unresolved host / Upgrade 12 to 14 Ubuntu/ Net Connection fine through browser

Tags: dns, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, ping, ubuntu-14.04

I recently upgraded to 'Trusty' i.e. Ubuntu 14.04. I tried pinging google.com through the terminal.

```
ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```

to remove and reinstall the resolv config, but to no avail.

Then I found the official bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1308378
I tried to do the following as instructed there:

```
cd /etc
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

But it gave an error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./resolv.conf’: File exists
```

Internet works fine through my firefox browser. In fact, I'm writing this question through the same system.

I set additional DNS servers in the WiFi settings to the google DNS servers:

```
8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

But to no avail.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved on Ask Ubuntu.
Here's the link to the answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/584528/unresolved-host-upgrade-12-to-14-ubuntu-net-connection-fine-through-browser/584540#584540